# UIWebView crash when tapping on textfield, dismissing keyboard, and tapping on textfield again

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

My app supports authorization from multiple cloud services (Dropbox, Google Drive and etc), and uses appropriate SDKs. Every SDK provides authorization by presenting a web view, where user can enter their credentials. The issue is that web views crash the app in the following situation:

1. Present the web view
2. Tap on any textfield
3. Keyboard appears, press on "Done" button
4. Tap on the textfield you tapped in step 2
5. Crash

Following information is printed into console.

```
2017-03-22 19:17:55.564 MyApplicationName[46315:16017957] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e63ff65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000111960deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e506f55 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 901
    3   UIKit                               0x000000011206fcd4 -[UIViewController _addChildViewController:performHierarchyCheck:notifyWillMove:] + 541
    4   UIKit                               0x00000001127e9581 -[UIInputWindowController changeToInputViewSet:] + 1420
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001127e218f -[UIInputWindowController moveFromPlacement:toPlacement:starting:completion:] + 369
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001127ea01b -[UIInputWindowController setInputViewSet:] + 983
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001127e1e17 -[UIInputWindowController performOperations:withAnimationStyle:] + 50
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001124fb397 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) setInputViews:animationStyle:] + 1275
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001120e0c89 -[UIResponder(UIResponderInputViewAdditions) reloadInputViews] + 81
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000112527604 -[UIWebBrowserView _reloadInputViewsAfterPotentialFocusRedirect] + 54
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001125274a9 -[UIWebBrowserView _endAllowingFocusRedirects] + 45
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001149d149b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001149bacd8 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 284
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001149d149b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001149b934b _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1738
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e5a03e9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e561939 __CFRunLoopRun + 2073
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e560e98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000115eafad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000111ee0676 UIApplicationMain + 171
    21  MyApplicationName                   0x000000010c161682 main + 114
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000114a0592d start + 1
    23  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Obviously, the issue appears when tapping on a textfield, so I decided to test it by simply opening google.com and tapping on a textfield there, to make sure that the app is going to crash.
The app didn't crash, but it did print the following info when I was showing/hiding keyboard.

```
2017-03-22 20:31:52.453 MyApplicationName[55324:16092779] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:elementDidFocusNode: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil
2017-03-22 20:31:54.985 MyApplicationName[55324:16092779] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:elementDidBlurNode: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil
2017-03-22 20:31:56.341 MyApplicationName[55324:16092779] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:elementDidFocusNode: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil
2017-03-22 20:31:58.029 MyApplicationName[55324:16092779] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:elementDidBlurNode: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil
2017-03-22 20:32:00.675 MyApplicationName[55324:16092779] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:elementDidFocusNode: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil
2017-03-22 20:32:02.872 MyApplicationName[55324:16092779] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:elementDidBlurNode: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil
```

I suspect that there is some issue with keyboard's toolbar, because if you take a look at [this gif](https://i.imgur.com/8DotpDq.mp4), you will notice that toolbar appears for the first time, but doesn't appear the second time, and QuickType appears for a short moment.

Additional info:
– I couldn't reproduce the issue in a sample project, i.e. there were no crashes or errors in logs when I tried to crash the app on google.com.
- It's unlikely that I have some gesture recognizers on UIWindow, checked there.

So the question is: how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In your UIInputWindowController, in changeToInputViewSet, you are trying to add a child view controller, but that child view controller is nil.  Find out why your view controller is nil, and fix that.  You have a repeatable sequence that reveals a crash. Put a breakpoint at the beginning of changeToInputViewSet, and step through watching what the value is of any viewControllers that you're using. There's your bug.

Comment: I've managed to find the cause of the bug by finding a commit that brought the bug and posted the answer here. But thanks for your input anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I managed to figure out what was causing this behaviour. This little extension below was causing the bug.

```
extension UIViewController {
    /**
     Simple shortcut for trivial cases.
     Adds a child controller to the view, that is a descendant of `self.view`.
     By default, child controller's view is stretched in the passed view.
     Use `constraintsSetupBlock` to setup constraints as you need.
     */
    func addChildViewController(childController: UIViewController, to view: UIView, constraintsSetupBlock: ((view: UIView, childControllerView: UIView) -> Void)? = nil) {
        guard view.isDescendantOfView(self.view) else {
            fatalError("`view` must be a descendand of `self.view`")
        }

        addChildViewController(childController)
        view.addSubview(childController.view)
        if let setupBlock = constraintsSetupBlock {
            setupBlock(view: view, childControllerView: childController.view)
        } else {
            childController.view.snp_makeConstraints(closure: { (make) in
                make.edges.equalTo(view)
            })
        }
        childController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }

    /**
     Simple shortcut for trivial cases.
     `childController` is optional purely for convenience.
    */
    func removeChildViewController(childController: UIViewController?) {
        guard let controller = childController else { return }
        controller.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
        controller.view.removeFromSuperview()
        controller.didMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    }
}
```

My guess is that names of the methods matched with some SDK's private methods, and at runtime the system chose my implementation, which led to a very unpleasant result.